# Graphics implementation of cellular automaton in C#?

Tags: cellular-automata

In my latest project i should implement cellular automaton in C#. I want help about how to create the image of array of cells and display present state and then display the whole of next state after a tick. I am also new to C#.
How should I implement the state changing effect?

Comment: What UI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Comment: This is not a very suitable question for this site. But there are plenty of Conway implementations available on the interweb, just look for them.

Answer (score 6):

- Create a control that can display a bitmap.
- Display the control.
- Write the state of the automaton to a bitmap.
- Set the control to display the bitmap.
- Compute the new state of the automaton.
- Go back to step three.

That's a vague answer because the question is vague. If you want a more specific answer then ask a more specific question.